# kibana 4.1 post filter on count aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Has anyone been able to figure out how to issue a post_filter in visualize to limit only results with a greater number of documents (count). Example: returned results blue 10, red 8, yellow 6, black 3 and what I desire is only to get results where the count of documents is greater than 7.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?